# Identifying license plate number of a thief's car from a Picture

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

I recently had the mail in my mailbox stolen from my home. I caught the whole thing on video and was able to identify the woman. Just a few days after the mail theft incident I went into a local post office and saw the same lady that stole our mail. Unfortunately the postal office I was in did not know the protocol to perform with the perpetrator in sight, and the police that I was on the phone with could not come and arrest her.

I was however able to capture the video a picture of her license plate but I cannot find it through free license plate searchers online. Is there any other sources that I am missing that may be able to decipher the license plate and or what state it might be in?[image]

I wish I had access to some database/map that gave me a map of Dodge Durango's in my area. Or some way I could have detected her phone then got her current location.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you just search for OCRs, you will find a lot of good ones. A simple search of OCR/OCR Matlab will do

Comment: Please specify your problem, if you know the license plate and looking for some database, you can simply go to the police. I assume you do not know the license plate number and have a video of it, and you are asking for something to help you to recognize it?